# More than 2 GPU‘s with NVLink

Tags: nvidia-graphics-card, dual-gpu, nvidia-rtx

I would like to know if it is possible to link up more than 2 Graphics Cards of the RTX Series.

Sincerely

lorhof1

Comment: https://www.nvidia.com/en-gb/data-center/nvlink/

Comment: This entirely depends on the card you have.  Consumer cards are limited to two cards.  I am pretty sure only Titan/Quadro supports more than 2 cards.  Nvidia and AMD both got away from more than 2 cards in SLI/Crossfire with the last 2 generations of their product

Comment: @Ramhound Thank you. But if i'd put in like 4 RTX 2080 cards, what would happen?

Comment: You would have to find a compatible NVLink that could connect to 4 cards.